# Grandparent method not accessible with interface injection, runs into a RuntimeBinderException at runtime

Tags: c#

I am trying to setup a framework for a websites that I can reuse. Hence I need to program it quite dynamically. Currently I am running into a RuntimeBinderException at runtime. My setup is (due to injection by interface):

**Database structure**

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T>
{
    List<T> List(string columnName, ExpandoObject value);
}

public class ReadOnlyRepository<T> : IReadOnlyRepository<T>
{
    public virtual List<T> List(string columnName, ExpandoObject value)
    {
        // Code that returns a list
    }
}


public interface IEditableRepository<T> : IReadOnlyRepository<T> { } 

public class EditableRepository<T> : ReadOnlyRepository<T>, IEditableRepository<T> { }


public interface IProductRepository : IEditableRepository<Product> { }

public class ProductRepository : EditableRepository<Product>, IProductRepository
{
    // This should inherit GetList(string columnName, ExpandoObject value)
    // from ReadOnlyRepository through EditableRepository
}
```

**Manager structure**

```
public interface IReadOnlyManager<T>
{
    List<T> List(string columnName, dynamic value);
    ExpandoObject BuildSingleExpandoObject(dynamic value);
}

public class ReadOnlyManager<T> : IReadOnlyManager<T>
{
    protected virtual IReadOnlyRepository<T> _repository { get; set; }

    public virtual List<T> List(string columnName, dynamic value)
    {
        return this._repository.List(columnName, BuildSingleExpandoObject(value));
    }

    public ExpandoObject BuildSingleExpandoObject(dynamic value)
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.value = value;
        return obj;
    }
}


public interface IEditableManager<T> : IReadOnlyManager<T> { } 

public class EditableManager<T> : ReadOnlyManager<T>, IEditableManager<T>
{
    protected new virtual IEditableRepository<T> _repository
    {
        get { return base._repository as IEditableRepository<T>; }
        set { base._repository = value; }
    }
}


public interface IProductManager : IEditableManager<Product> { }

public class ProductManager : EditableManager<Product>, IProductManager
{
    // Getter and setter to convert repository to the right on when called by parent
    protected new IProductRepository _repository
    {
        get { return base._repository as IProductRepository ; }
        set { base._repository = value; }
    }

    public ProductManager(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this._repository = productRepository;
    }

    public new List<Product> List(string columnName, dynamic value)
    {
        // Different code then in ReadOnlyManager

        return this._repository.List(columnName, BuildSingleExpandoObject(value));
        // Here I get a RuntimeBinderException at runtime, telling me that _repository
        // does not have a method List(string id);
    }
}
```

The Exception that has been thrown is:

```
Exception has occurred: Run-time exception (line 124): 'ProductApp.Program.IProductRepository' does not contain a definition for 'List'

Stack Trace:
[Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'ProductApp.Program.IProductRepository' does not contain a definition for 'List']
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , IProductRepository , String , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at ProductApp.Program.ProductManager.List(String columnName, Object value) :line 124
   at ProductApp.Program.Main(String[] args) :line 13
```

Fiddle is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2F5oI7).

If I combine ReadOnly and Editable to Base (BaseRepository and BaseManager) this system works fine, but I want to keep a more agile construction.

However, it seems to not like this setup where there is an additional layer. My guess is that it goes wrong at the EditableManager _repository property setter, but I have no clue. Does anyone know how to address this issue?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your code does not seem to be real code, `pulbic virtual List<T> List<T>(string id)` is no valid code at all. Oh, and maybe also post the exact exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @Compufreak sorry this is not something that I can make easier then this. My company works through injection by interface, hence the need for so many layers. Though I already was in the process of claryfing and editing typos

Comment: The issue is not that your example is too complicated, it is not complete or verifiable. Please read the article I linked above.
I am asking this because it's hard to wrap my head around the code you provided, it would be way more easy if it would be actually possible to try it out, or at least have a clue by an exact exception message and stacktrace.

Comment: @Compufreak added the exception, and I will add more code to it so it resembles more my real code, but I fear it will get convoluted and hard to read because of it

Comment: Your exception message says its looking for "List", but the interface only provides a "GetList"-Method. This either is your issue or there is missing code, or I am misunderstanding the exception message :>

Comment: @Compufreak I heavily redacted my code to simplify it. Then you kinda throw me off with "pulbic virtual List<T> List<T>(string id) is no valid code at all." (pulbic, not the List<T> List<T> thing) so I redacted it again. All should be as it is

Comment: I just tried to get a running example from your code and - like @CodeCaster said - it does not produce the error. You might be able to use it as a starting point - it takes way less time to solve your problem if you produce something runnable like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DiZTVM

Comment: Sorry folks, I was too minimalistic. My apologies, updated the code to show how it really is

Comment: The fiddle now returns the exception that I am getting

Comment: Can you share the link to your fiddle?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2F5oI7 , will add it to the question as well

Comment: Now I can reproduce the problem, great - I didn't find the cause for your issue yet and have quite some stuff to do right now, I'll try to come back when I find more time - it's quite interesting. For now I'll give an upvote so maybe someone else comes accross this question and knows what the issue is - it's a good and reproducable question now.

Comment: This has something to do with the strange way function resolution with dynamic objects works and the multiple inheritance paths in this design.  Note that `return this._repository.List(columnName, (ExpandoObject)BuildSingleExpandoObject(value));` succeeds.

Comment: @Compufreak thank you

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft that seems to be the solution. Can this be solved through an adaptation of BuildSingleExpandoObject(value) as well so that it explicitly returns an ExpandoObject?